# Python bypassing @property getter methods ambiguity

Tags: python, oop, decorator, python-decorators, ambiguity

I know that this is a badly written code. But why does this behave this way?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, f, l):
        self.first = f
        self.last = l
        
    @property
    def first(self):
        return self._first
    @first.setter
    def first(self, new):
        self._first = new
        

a = A("ab", "cd")
print(a.first)
```

Why does this return "ab"? Shouldn't the @property getter method be invoked on **a.first** and raise an attribute error?

Comment: In your `__init__` you did a `self.first = f` which calls the setter defined using the method passed to `@first.setter`.

Comment: Please try to trace through the logic of the code carefully. When `self.first = f` happens in `__init__`, what do you expect that to do? Hint: look closely at `@first.setter`.

Comment: @metatoaster, yes in __init__() the setter is invoked. Thanks

Comment: This code is only bad because you shouldn't use a `property` here at all, and just a regular attribute. But other than that, this is *how you would use a property* if you were supposed to.